# Django | where to iterate: views or template

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering where is the best place to build the code I need: template or views.

Let's say I have 3 lists and inside some dicts:

```
sell = [{'date__month': 1, 'date__year': 2020, 'sells_by_month': 15}, {'date__month': 5, 'date__year': 2020, 'sells_by_month': 115}]
payments = [{'date__month': 5, 'date__year': 2020, 'payments_by_month': 18}]
provider = [{'date__month': 4, 'date__year': 2020, 'providers_by_month': 200}, {'date__month': 5, 'date__year': 2020, 'providers_by_month': 320}]
```

For every month/year I need to check if there is any sells, payments or providers. I need to display in templates something like that

```
Period  Sells   Payments   Provider 
01-2020 15      0          0     
02-2020 0       0          0
03-2020 0       0          0
04-2020 0       0          200
05-2020 115     18         320
06-2020 0       0          0
```

I can build another dict with a loop in views.py but anyway I'll need to create another loop to display all this table in templates. So I guess this could take too much time with a desnecessary looping in views.py.

Is it possible to create some code directly in templates with just one if-else loop condition OR it's a good pratice to build the whole dict in views.py?

What do you think?

Comment: Business logic should always be handled in the view, not in the template. So the view should prepare some sort of (list of) dictionaries.

Comment: I recommend to use view, which by default should return all the values.. However, you should use filter condition or params to filter the output constructed in view!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to create some code directly in templates with just one if-else loop condition OR it's a good pratice to build the whole `dict` in views.py?

Possible, maybe yes, but no it is not good practice at all. A template is about *rendering* data in a pleasant form. A view should handle the *business logic*. While there is a "*gray zone*", usually from the moment in involves function calls, arbitrary dictionary lookups, etc. you better do this in a view. In fact Django's template language is *deliberately* restricted to discourage doing these things in a view.

We can make a list of dictionaries with the data with:

```
def records_to_dict(records, key):
    return {(r['date__year'], r['date__month']): r[key] for r in records}

dict_sell = records_to_dict(sell, 'sells_by_month')
dict_payments = records_to_dict(payments, 'payments_by_month')
dict_provider = records_to_dict(provider, 'providers_by_month')
```

Next we can summarize this, for example by looping over the months:

```
half_year = [
    {'year': y, 'month': m, 'sells': dict_sell.get((y, m), 0), 'payments': dict_payments.get((y, m), 0), 'providers': dict_provider.get((y, m), 0)}
    for y in range(2020, 2021)
    for m in range(1, 7)
]
```

Now `half_year` will contain data that looks like:

```
[{'month': 1, 'payments': 0, 'providers': 0, 'sells': 15, 'year': 2020},
 {'month': 2, 'payments': 0, 'providers': 0, 'sells': 0, 'year': 2020},
 {'month': 3, 'payments': 0, 'providers': 0, 'sells': 0, 'year': 2020},
 {'month': 4, 'payments': 0, 'providers': 200, 'sells': 0, 'year': 2020},
 {'month': 5, 'payments': 18, 'providers': 320, 'sells': 115, 'year': 2020},
 {'month': 6, 'payments': 0, 'providers': 0, 'sells': 0, 'year': 2020}]
```

Now you can render this in a template, for example:

```
<table>
{% for item in half_year %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.year }}-{{ item.month }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sells }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.payments }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.providers }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: in this case it's necessary to use 2 'for loops', one inside the view and another one inside the template. In applications with so many data, wouldn't this overcharge the server? I know you said before to keep away the logic from the template, but I'm thinking about performance: what if we build just one 'for-loop' inside the template? Would this be faster? Sorry for disturbing, I'm just trying to understand how Django works...

Comment: @FelipeDourado: usually the template interpreter is quite slow compared to the Python functions. In fact often if one wants to a view faster, it pays of to try to turn the template rendering in string processing in Python views. But note that usually performance of a webapp scales with the number of queries, not that much with the functions. After all, data you process should first be communicated by the database, and this tends to be a more severe bottleneck.