# Html conditional rendering good practice in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to show an empty page design if there isnt any data from admin. I know it can be achieved using {% empty %} or if condition on template. But, please let me know if the below code is good to go ?

In my views.py,

```
if books.exists():
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'nobook.html')
```

Is the above a good practice or should i try with

```
{% if not books %}
render this...
{%else %}
render this ...
{% endif %}
```

Please guide on which to use and which is a good practice ?

Comment: You can use any because it is essentially the exact same thing. Both are python. The location where you do it is different. I prefer the first way, but you can use the second too.

Comment: Wont there be any impact or cons using the first ?

Comment: No. You can either check the condition here or pass the data to the template and check there.it should be the exact same

Comment: IMO, the latter is better for class-based views. They often define "template_name", so with conditional template you can rely on inherited class methods. If you use function-based views, there won't be any notable difference. Also conditional template makes it easier not to violate DRY principle (or you should have 'index.html', 'nobook.html' and '_index_common.html' to store template parts that are common for both).

Comment: Both will do the work. But, In my opinion, all these conditions checking should be done in ```views```. You only show in templates what your ```views``` return.

Comment: Understood, i have base layouts - so just rendering the needed on 'nobook.html'. As thought it would be better to do things on view rather than doing stuffs inside the templates @SUTerliakov

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what information you will return back to the user, imagine that is just message error if we don't have `books` in that case you can use `messages` core as the following example.

```py
if not books:
    messages.error(self, "There are not books available")
return render(request, template.html)
```

But if is a change in a short title you can use an `{% if not books %}` and add the short title in each block.

But in the cases that the views have different data at all for example different design or diferent sections then you can use

```
if not books:
    return render(request, 'firsttemplate.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'secondtemplate.html')
```

And in other cases where you have an HttpResponse and other response that is for example an excel file then in that cases you must use defenitely the logic in views.py:

```
if not books:
    # return render html
else:
    # return excel file response
```

And in the last escenary is not posible to make the condition in a template.

And in performance I think you can use the `debug-toolbar` to make a conclusion in it I don't think it can be better in one place or other because querysets are lazy and in whatever place will take the same time to hit the database.

Respect to good practices the best practice is to add the bussiness logic in the views or if it is posible in the model not in templates check out this link: [Django | where to iterate: views or template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760200/django-where-to-iterate-views-or-template#)

Comment: Will there be any performance difference in using template if and direct view if's ? As there is no difference in using at view or in template, thought of using inside view itself rather than depending on templates ! What do you say ?

Comment: @pegawol169 checkout the las part of my answer where I edited to answer the question about performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it all depends on how different the two cases are. If most of the html is the same in both cases, use the conditional in the template. If the pages that the user sees are completely different, use two templates and render the appropriate one.

Neither is automatically to be criticised.

Comment: I think if the conditional is part of business logic it has to be put in the view or if it is possible in the model not in the template. Is a best practice to put business logic in the model if it is posible.